# Find index word in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program in Python that prints keywords (words starting with uppercase letters) along with the word number (multiple words) in the output of a text. If no word with this attribute is found in the text, print it in the None output. Words at the beginning of a sentence should not be considered as an index word. (Start word number from one)

Numbers are not counted except index words. The only symbol used in a sentence except for a period is a comma. Be sure to remove the semicolon if it was at the end of the word.

input
The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the deprived areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and friendship.
This video was captured by one of our heroes who wishes peace.

outputstrong text
2:Persian
3:League
15:Iran
17:Persian
18:League

how can i fix it?://**strong text**

```
enter code here
import re

inputText = ""

# we will use this regex pattern to check if a word is started with upperCase
isUpperCase = re.compile("^([A-Z])\w+")

# we will store upperCase words in this array
result = []
# number of word in the hole input
wordIndex = 0

# separate sentences
sentences = inputText.strip().split('.')

for s in sentences:
 # get array of words in each sentence
 words = s.strip().split(' ')

 for index, word in enumerate(words):
 # increase wordIndex
 wordIndex += 1

 # just pass first word
 if index == 0:
 continue

 # check regex and if true add word and wordIndex to result
 if isUpperCase.match(word):
 result.append({
 "index": wordIndex,
 "word": word
 })


# finally print result
for word in result:
 print(word["index"], ": ", word["word"])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: This site isn't a code writing service. What code have you already tried?

Comment: Right, I forgot to put the code and edited it again

Answer (score 0):

You can add each uppercase word to a dictionary with their index values (plus one). I noticed that you didn't return `The` or `This` but I don't know what the rule is there so I just added an exemption for those two words.

```py
import collections
uppercase_letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'F', 'H', 'I', \
                     'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', \
                     'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

mystring = 'The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the deprived areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and friendship. This video was captured by one of our heroes who wishes peace.'
counter_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

counter = 0
overall_counter = 0
for i in mystring.split('.'):
    counter = 0
    for j in i.split():
        counter += 1
        overall_counter += 1
        if counter == 1:
            continue
        if j[0] in uppercase_letters:
            counter_dict[i].append(overall_counter)

counter_list = []
    
for i in counter_dict.values():
    for j in i:
        counter_list.append(j)

for i in sorted(counter_list):
    print(str(i) + ':', mystring.split()[i-1].rstrip('.'), '', sep=' ', end='', flush=True)

>>> 2: Persian 3: League 15: Iran 17: Persian 18: League
```

Comment: From question: _"Words at the beginning of a sentence should not be considered as an index word. (Start word number from one)"_.

Comment: Thanks @RobertoCaboni overlooked that, have edited my answer

Comment: Thank you, but your answer in the test did not answer, unfortunately

Comment: Do you have a link to the test @rani because the output of this is clearly your expected output

Comment: Try with the altered print statement, it might be the case that they need to be printed on the same line and with colons

Comment: I registered for a course and the test is done online by the .Quora site